# Alternative to pandas concat

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concatenate two data frames with

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index(["t", "tc"]), df2.set_index(["t", "tc"])], axis=1)
```

It can happen that in df1, the index is not unique. In that case, I want the corresponding entry in df2 to be inserted into all the rows with that index. Unfortunately, instead of doing that, concat gives me an error.I thought `ignore_index = True` might help, but I still get the error `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`
Is there an alternative to concat that does what I want?

For example:
df1

```
t  tc a
a  1  5
b  1  6
a  1  7
```

df2:

```
t tc b
a 1  8
b 1  10
```

result(after resetting the index):

```
t tc a b
a 1  5 8
b 1  6 10
a 1  7 8
```

Comment: can you post the sample data and expected output

Comment: Yes, merge, append: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html Actually concat should work, just need to set the axis on which to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) you can get where you need

```
df1.merge(df2, on =['t', 'tc'])
#result
    t   tc  a   b
0   a   1   5   8
1   a   1   7   8
2   b   1   6   10
```